# Calculating overtime with momentjs and ranges

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have start and end times for any given day in 24 hour time.

I want to calculate how many hours were worked within a specific time range.

For example, if

```
startTime = '11:00';
endTime = '21:30';

calcOverTime(startTime, endTime) // result 1 hour worked between 8pm and 10pm
```

how can I count how many hours were worked between 8pm and 10pm.

I want the output to be the calculated number of hours and minutes in that range.

I have tried extendedMomentjs and ranges but the overlap and contains functionality only return true or false.

Comment: @KenY-N I have tried creating two ranges with extendMomentjs where one simply is start and end time worked, and the other is 8pm to 10pm. The overlap and contains function just return true but i want to count hours within range not determine if there was any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var startTime = moment('1970-01-01 11:00');
var endTime = moment('1970-01-01 21:30');

var dayEndTime = moment('1970-01-01 20:00');

var overtime = moment.duration(0);

if (endTime.isAfter(dayEndTime)) {
 var time = startTime.isAfter(dayEndTime) ? startTime : dayEndTime;
 overtime = moment.duration(endTime.diff(time));
}

console.log('As Hours: ', overtime.as('hours'));
console.log('As Minutes: ', overtime.as('minutes'));
console.log('Get only Hours: ', overtime.get('hours'));
console.log('Get only Minutes: ', overtime.get('minutes'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hours = (startTime, finishTime) => {
  const [startHours, startMinutes] = startTime.split(':');
  const [finishHours, finishMinutes] = finishTime.split(':');
  const startTimeinMinutes = (parseInt(startHours) * 60) + parseInt(startMinutes);
  const finishTimeinMinutes = (parseInt(finishHours) * 60) + parseInt(finishMinutes);
  const totalMinutes = finishTimeinMinutes - startTimeinMinutes;
  const minutes = totalMinutes % 60;
  const hours = (totalMinutes - minutes)/60;
  return `${hours}:${minutes < 10 ? '0' : ''}${minutes}`;
};

console.log(hours('11:00', '21:30'));
```

Comment: I didn't parse the strings to int, it is fixed now.

Comment: This is just giving me the hours between the start and end, Im after how many hours where calculated between a range for example 8pm and 10pm.

So for example '19:00' to '21:00' would result in '01:00'

Answer (score 0):

If we are using `moment.js`, this appears to work:

```
d = moment.duration(moment(endTime, "HH:mm").diff(moment(startTime, "HH:mm")));
```

This gives a `Duration` object that you could print out in various ways, like:

```
d.as('hours');
```

Gives:

> 10.5

Or:

```
console.log(`${d.hours()}:${d.minutes() < 10 ? '0' : ''}${d.minutes()}`);
```

This gives:

> 10:30

BTW, since you say "how can I count how many hours were worked between 8pm and 10pm.", try this:

```
d = moment.duration(moment(endTime, "HH:mm").diff(moment("20:00", "HH:mm")));
```

Handling working past midnight is left as an exercise for the reader...